# OSAtomicAdd32 variant in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm, looking for an alternative to `OSAtomicAdd32` since it's deprecated in the Apple headers. What is the C++11 variant of it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++11 way to go would be to use `std::atomic_int_32_t` or `std::atomic_int` (If `sizeof(int) == 4` on your system). These types can be included from the header `<atomic>` and the reference page for them can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

Comment: Well, make the variable be of type `std::atomic_int_32_t`, and then use `+=` on it to do an atomic add.  Note that this is a change from the `OSAtomicAdd32` model.  With that, you could do an atomic operation on any (suitably aligned) variable.  With C++ atomics, you can *only* do atomic operations on `atomic` variables - but you are guaranteed that *all* operations on such variables will be atomic.